# Custom category for posts via XMLRPC

Tags: categories, xml-rpc

I have a blog located at one site that when I post into a category, it will auto-post via XMLRPC to another site of mine.  This functionality works, but I would like to assign a category to these posts.

Is there any way to do this?  The only site that will be posting this way is controlled by me, so I don't care if it's global.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by sending the 5th parameter to wp.newPost, like this:

```
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request( "wp.newPost", array( 1, $xmlrpc_username, $xmlrpc_password, $content, $terms) );
```

Please note the **$terms** should be in this format: **'Taxonomy names as keys, array of term IDs as values'**, according to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#Parameters_3).

FYI, here is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585307/publish-a-post-using-xml-rpc-wordpress-api-and-python-with-category) related to your question.

Comment: I've looked through my code and can't seem to find where to put that.  can you advise?

cheers

Comment: Could you paste your code to your question? The point of my code is you need to add a `$terms` parameter to the wp.newPost request, which is often left behind.